# Pull Information from Google Fusion Table

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

This should be pretty obvious, but I've spent the past two days searching for this and included a coworker, who also can't find a solution:

**How do you pull specific information from a Google Fusion Table?**

I can't even find this information on the Google Fusion Table API site, and I haven't found a single Stack Overflow question that answers this, either.

To give you an idea of my project, I have a Fusion Layer called "layer" that contains County information. I want it to display county names.

I have an addListener Google Map event if you click on the county, but I can't make the text appear for each county without running through the layer object. Here's the code for that:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "resize", function(evt) {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(evt.row['Center_Lat'].value,evt.row['Center_Long'].value)

    var m = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        label: {
            color: 'white',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            text: evt.row['County Name'].value
        },
        icon: {
            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(11, 50),
            url: 'default_marker.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(22, 40),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(11, 40),
        },
    });
});
```

How do I make that function run for each element of the Fusion Table? Or, even more specifically, how can I pull information from the FusionLayer object? As I said, i can't even find this information on Google's API pages.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test//v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser_encryptedID.html) (but using counties instead of states)?

Comment: @geocodezip No, I don't want the labels to appear on click. I want the labels to always be there, so I'm trying to figure out how to simply pull this information from the FusionTable. If the FusionLayer object "layer" exists, how do I pull information labeled "County Name" from the second row? Once I learn that, I can figure out how to loop through all of the rows and create markers for each row.

Comment: The example in my comment is querying the fusion table for the state names (it happens to be displaying them in the sidebar and the infowindow)

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it to work. My problems were in the order it loaded the .js files. Thank you for your help!